# Network Printing with USB Printer - No "Server" Tab on Printer Options

Tags: networking, printing

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS I've tried numerous searches, can't find anything that seems applicable.  In the picture shown in the link below, and every other one I've looked at, there is a [Server] Tab. My System -> Administration -> Printing doesn't have any tabs. How do I fix this?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu

TIA,

Ron

---

Thanks.
Yes it opens a a gui, but it's the same tab-less printer gui.

---

Standard 16.04 LTS = Yes

---

[Printers Tab Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFdo9.png)

Comment: if you paste `system-config-printer` into a terminal, do you get a gui interface open up, and does it have a server option left-most?

Comment: so this is a standard 16.04 (unity?) ubuntu? can you enclose a screenshot of what you get .. to help us understand what you are seeing please